# issuing multiple (check-sat) calls until it returns unsat

Tags: z3

The release notes for z3 version 4.6 mention a new feature "issuing multiple (check-sat) calls until it returns unsat".
Is this an equivalent for ALLSAT?
Where can I find any further documentation or an example for this feature?

Comment: Yes, this is about Optimization calls. It is not related to AllSAT. There is no built-in method for ALL-SAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this was for addressing this issue: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1008

An ALLSAT command is not supported by z3; though it would be easy to code it using the "assert the negation of the previous model and re-check" loop. Most high-level interfaces provide this as a layer on top of what's possible using SMT-Lib2. If you do want support for this, it might be best to first convince the SMTLib folks (http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/) so a standard way of doing so would be developed and can be implemented by multiple solvers.

Comment: I agree that using check-sat in a loop and feeding back the negated model back as assertion is an easy way to mimic ALLSAT. However I can see from my results, that the internal reset strategy is in no way influenced by the outer loop. It would be nice to have at least some influence from the outside.

Comment: Additionally, there are also questions around how all-sat should behave in the presence of quantifiers. (A common strategy is print only differing prefix-existentials and once you hit a for-all, leave everything else alone.) But none of this is well specified or universally agreed upon. I think there's room here for both the standard (i.e., SMTLib) to set the basic expectations, and the tool (z3/yices etc.) to implement how the "next-model" is constructed as you are alluding to.